# Shutdown pc in Go

Tags: go, system-calls

After looking in the go documentation this seems to be what I am looking for https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Shutdown , what do you need to pass to this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about system shutdown, but about [shutting down connections](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown). I think for system shutdown you need to use `os/exec` and proper commands for current OS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use syscall.Reboot(syscall.LINUX_REBOOT_CMD_POWER_OFF).

Comment: That applies only to Linux based systems but not Windows for example.

Comment: This instruction is violent power off like removing power supply from your computer